# Как сделать рекурсивный запрос к БД?

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня имеется следующая таблица категорий

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача при выборе категории высшей иерархии подтянуть все его подкатегории - создать коллекцию категорий дерева. Вопрос такой: как реализовать такую задачу с помощью Entity Framework?

Пробую написать sql запрос, но получаю исключение ""

```
CREATE RECURSIVE VIEW categories (CategoryID, SubcatID) 
AS 
SELECT 'Id' AS SubcatID, 
    'ParentCategoryId' as CategoryID
    FROM public."Category"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.Id AS SubcatID, 
    cte.Id AS CategoryID
    FROM categories
    INNER JOIN public."Category" AS c ON c.ParentCategoryId = categories.CategoryID

ERROR: ОШИБКА:  столбец c.parentcategoryid не существует
LINE 10:  INNER JOIN public."Category" AS c ON c.ParentCategoryId = c...
                                               ^
HINT:  Возможно, предполагалась ссылка на столбец "c.ParentCategoryId".
```

Comment: Одна тема - один вопрос! Либо вы спрашиваете, как сделать SQL-запрос в Postgres, либо как его использовать в EF. Это не я такой злой, это правило сайта.

Comment: В статье, ссылку на которую я вам давал, есть примеры sql-запросов:  Выборка поддерева по заданному узлу, Выборка всех предков, Проверка, входит ли узел в поддерево.

Comment: Документация: [Postgresql CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html). Ещё: [PostgreSQL Recursive View](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-views/postgresql-recursive-view/).

Comment: Как потом всё это дело использовать в EF Core. Либо сырые SQL-запросы вызывать: [Raw SQL Queries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql). Либо можно замапить: [User-defined function mapping](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping).

Comment: Наверное, единственная ORM, которая умеет делать CTE прямо в коде C#, это [linq2db](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/CTE.html). Можно использовать её одновременно с EF. Или использовать расширение [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore).

Comment: Всё, чем мог, тем помог! Ждём спецов по Постгресу. Авось кто откликнется.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/269497/